# Freeing a data module which contains a TJvAppDBStorage raises an access violation in TComponent.RemoveNotification()

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, jvcl

I have a data module which I can not free (funny as it might sound). Whether I try to destroy it manually, or let another component (even `Application`) do it for me, I get an AV with this stack trace:

```
exception class   : EAccessViolation
exception message : Access violation at address 0048FC2B in module 'Instruments.exe'. Read of address 80808088.

main thread ($1e28):
0048fc2b Instruments.exe System.Classes    TComponent.RemoveNotification
00408a01 Instruments.exe System         57 @Halt0
00ac86f0 Instruments.exe Instruments    82 initialization
```

This data module contains a bunch of `TADOxxx` components, plus two `TJvDataSource`, one `TApplicationEvents`, one `TClientDataSet`, and one `TJvAppDBStorage`. Its code contains nothing more than opening the ADO connection, writing a few records to a table, running a few queries, etc. (nothing unusual). It doesn't *own* any other components besides what I mentioned above. I'm puzzled as to where does this bogus call to `RemoveNotificaion()` originate from. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

After removing the `TJvAppDBStorage`, I can destroy the data module. Here's the component's properties:

```
object AppStorage: TJvAppDBStorage
  StorageOptions.BooleanStringTrueValues = 'TRUE, YES, Y'
  StorageOptions.BooleanStringFalseValues = 'FALSE, NO, N'
  DataSource = dsConfiguration
  KeyField = 'Key'
  SectionField = 'Section'
  SubStorages = <>
  ValueField = 'Value'
  Left = 272
  Top = 304
end
```

Has anyone ever used `JvAppDBStorage`? Is this its *normal* and *expected* behavior?

Comment: I think `Application` would be a better owner. That said, why not carry on passing `nil` and instead call `Free` on the data module yourself. If you want help debugging the AV, give more information. Provide exact error message, code where it is raised, and a call stack.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan updated the question... As the stack trace shows, the exception is not raised in my code.

Comment: Yeah, that's to be expected. Where do you create your data module? In your .dpr file? If so then I would suggest that you call `Free` on it after `Application.Run` returns. And don't make it owned by the main form. So, carry on passing `nil` as the owner. If that fails then we at least have more control over when the destructor is invoked. And it will be easier to debug.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm creating the data module in `OnCreate()` of my main form. When I pass `nil` as `Owner`, I free it in `OnDestroy()` of the main form.

Comment: If you free it in `OnDestroy` then there should be no leaks. Changing `Owner` is not going to help you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's exactly what I don't understand. I have five data modules, of which four are behaving. This one doesn't like to be released. :-( It owns one `TADOConnection`, four `TADOQuery`, one `TApplicationEvents`, one `TClientDataset`, two `TJvDataSource`, one `TJvAppDBStorage`, and one `TADOCommand` components on in, and I'm not creating any components in its code. I'm beginning to suspect Jv components...

Comment: Well, changing `Owner` is going to do nothing. If you are already calling the destructor in the main form's `OnDestroy`, then there should be no leak. You need to debug the leak itself. Your proposed solution is not a real solution.

Comment: If you have 4 other datamodules that are behaving, have you tried just rebguilding it step by step to find the culprit?

Comment: @PieterB I'm in the process of doing that exactly. Removing components one by one, and running the application

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I rephrased my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've no experience with `JvAppDBStorage` but I can make a guess as to what is happening.

This component stores settings to a database, as specified by the `DataSource` property of the `JvAppDBStorage` instance. In your case that is `dsConfiguration`. So, for this all to work you need for `dsConfiguration` to be available whenever `AppStorage` reads and writes settings. I'll bet that `dsConfiguration` has already been destroyed when `AppStorage` attempts to store to it. I expect that happens when `AppStorage` is freed. So the explanation for the problem is that `dsConfiguration` is freed before `AppStorage`.

The solution will be to make sure that `dsConfiguration` is still alive when `AppStorage` is freed.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I just cut and paste the `JvAppDBStorage` component, and the problem was solved :-)